# npm install windows-build-tools on windows

Tags: windows, npm, npm-install, windows-build-tools

```
OS - Windows-10
node - v8.12.0
npm - 6.4.1
```

The command I'm using (run as administrator):

```
npm install --global --production --verbose windows-build-tools
```

```
> windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall C:\Users\winuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
> node ./dist/index.js

Downloading vs_BuildTools.exe
[============================================>] 100.0% of 1.12 MB (1.12 MB/s)
Downloaded vs_BuildTools.exe. Saved to C:\Users\winuser\.windows-build-tools\vs_BuildTools.exe.

Starting installation...
Launched installers, now waiting for them to finish.
This will likely take some time - please be patient!

Status from the installers:
---------- Visual Studio Build Tools ----------
2021-11-23T15:34:08 : Verbose : [InstalledProductsProviderImpl]: Stream was closed
2021-11-23T15:34:08 : Verbose : [InstallerImpl]: Rpc connection was closed.
2021-11-23T15:34:08 : Verbose : [InstallerImpl]: Stream was closed
2021-11-23T15:34:09 : Verbose : Completed notifying all clients that the update is starting
2021-11-23T15:34:09 : Verbose : Updating installer [bootstrapperArguments: -- /finalizeInstall install --in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_bootstrapper\vs_setup_bootstrapper_202111231533560643.json --norestart --quiet --includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --locale en-US --activityId 61b330e5-53cf-4d1e-819c-b2acdd48ed03]
------------------- Python --------------------
Python 2.7.18 is already installed, not installing again.
```

It doesn't comes out, have tried to install couple of times. In both the times it looks stuck at same point.

The following command tried, it installed but was showing `Could not install Visual Studio Build Tools.`

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0
```

```
Starting installation...
Launched installers, now waiting for them to finish.
This will likely take some time - please be patient!

Status from the installers:
---------- Visual Studio Build Tools ----------
Successfully installed Visual Studio Build Tools.
---------- Visual Studio Build Tools ----------
Successfully installed Visual Studio Build Tools.
------------------- Python --------------------
Python 2.7.18 is already installed, not installing again.

Could not install Visual Studio Build Tools.
Please find more details in the log files, which can be found at
C:\Users\winuser\.windows-build-tools
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

You should install [visual studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) manually and select .NET and C/C++ components during setup. I had the same problem and that worked out for me.